# How to store a data with javascript using objects

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop, store

I wrote this code:

```
$(".awesome").click(function () {
        var toStore = $("input[name=name]").val();
        if (/^[A-Za-z]+ [A-Za-z]+$/.test(toStore)) {
            $("#contain").children().fadeOut(1000);
            $("#contain").delay(1000).queue(function () {
                $("#contain").append("<h1>Welcome to My Quiz : " + toStore + "</br>" +
                    "Youll Get 10 Questions To Answer </br> " +
                    "Here Is the First One:Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom? </h1>");

                var allQuestions = [
                    {question: "Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom?",
                        choices: ["David Cameron",
                            "Gordon Brown",
                            "Winston Churchill",
                            "Tony Blair"],
                        correctAnswer: 0}
                ];
                $("#contain").append("<form><input type='radio' name='ans1' value='David Cameron'>David Cameron</br>" +
                    " <input type='radio' name='ans1' value='Gordon Brown'>Gordon Brown</br>" +
                    "<input type='radio' name = 'ans1' value = 'Winston Churchill' > Winston Churchill </br>" +
                    "<input type='radio' name='ans1' value='Tony Blair'>Tony Blair</br>" +
                    "<input type='submit' value='Submit' name='submit'></form>");
                $("input[name=submit]").click(function () {
                    var correctAnswer;
                    if ($("input[name=ans1]").val()) {
                        var x = "choices";
                        allQuestions[x] = "David Cameron";
                        for (var x in allQuestions) {
                            return correctAmswer = false;

                            if (allQuestions[x] === "David Cameron") {

                                return correctAnswer = true;
                            } else {
                                return correctAnswer = false;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        } else {
            alert("You Must Put a Valid Name");
        }
    });
});
```

Now as you can see I have an Object called "allQuestions".
Now I have 3 properties: "question" "choices" and "correct answer".
Afterwards I have a submit button that if you click it it checks the value of the input name="ans1",then I loop through all of the choices in Object "allQuestions";
if then answer is "David Cameron" I want it to store the correctAnswer to be 1 instead of 0;
else I don't want to store the correctAnswer and it remains 0 because I have more questions
afterwards.
Any suggestions how to do so?

Comment: You have a "return correctAmswer = false;" in the start of your for.. in loop. Is that intended? That _assigns_ the value 'false' to correctAnswer and then returns the value 'false' but correctAnswer won't keep its value afterwards.

Comment: no it wasnt intended that i wrote correctanmswer,but the code from here:for (var x in allQuestions) {
                            return correctAmswer = false;

                            if (allQuestions[x] === "David Cameron") {

                                return correctAnswer = true;
                            } else {
                                return correctAnswer = false;
                            }       is ont seems to me to be a good solution. or am i wrog and im doing it well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The first problem is that direct event handling does not work with dynamically added elements if you register your event handler before the elements are added. In your case, I think it works because you register you event handler after the elements are added. But you should change it to:

  $("#contain").on("click","input[name=submit]", function(){ your function})
- The second problem is that the way you access your allQuestions is not correct because it's an array. It should be: allQuestions[0][x];
- The third problem like @Benjamin Gruenbaum mentioned.

Comment: can you please explain further more what allQuestions[0][x] does? i see when i put it in console.log that it get's my an array of my choices. meaning containing = ["David Cameron","Gordon Brown","Winston Churchill","Tony Blair"] do i need to do a for in loop in allQuestions[0][x] to check if the value of input name="ans1" is "David Cameron"??

Comment: allQuestions[0][x] means: accessing the first question (index = 0) and get the property [x]. In your case: x=choices